# How to force commit changes on chrome local storage

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome-extension, local-storage

I have an extension which using chrome local storage. I connect to the local storage with another application while chrome is open and I see the changes in this external application only when I'm closing chrome. I guess the changes are done just for the current session and I need to commit those changes. If I'm totally wrong please tell me, but if not, do I have a way to commit the changes made on the chrome extension local storage through javascript?

Thanks.

Comment: Which browser storage technology are you using? Based on your [sqlite] tag, sounds like WebSQL. Not the same thing as [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.org/storage.html). Please clarify.

Comment: I connect to the storage using sqlite, i success to connect to the storage and querying it. so I'm sure its sqlite. but in javascript of course im just performing stuff like:

localStorage["key"] = value

can I commit those changes?

Thanks.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Sorry, I don't know of a way of forcibly committing your localStorage modifications. I suspect this sort of control is not exposed to JS (by design).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found out the problem. Im updating the storage using sqlite through another application and I guess it causing problems. the changes are instantly committed.